# Why is the first Link item being skipped?

Tags: d3.js

I've got a fairly simple visualization I'm trying to put together, but having a slight issue with the processing.

If I use the following snippet then everything works as expected:

```
var lines = svg.selectAll("line")
                        .data(data.links)
                        .enter()
                        .append("svg:line")
                            .attr("x1", function(d) { return findNode(data.nodes, d.source).x;})
                            .attr("y1", function(d) { return findNode(data.nodes, d.source).y;})
                            .attr("x2", function(d) { return findNode(data.nodes, d.target).x;})
                            .attr("y2", function(d) { return findNode(data.nodes, d.target).y;})
                            .style("stroke", "#838383")
                            .style("stroke-width", 1)
                            .style("marker-end", "url(#end-arrow)");
```

If I switch this however to use a slightly different one, using paths:

```
var paths = svg.selectAll("path")
                        .data(data.links)
                        .enter()
                        .append("svg:path")
                            .attr("d", function(d) { 
                                debugger;
                                var src = findNode(data.nodes, d.source);
                                var tgt = findNode(data.nodes, d.target);
                                var xi = d3.interpolateNumber(src.x, tgt.x);
                                var curvature = 0.8;

                                return "M" + src.x + "," + src.y
                                     + "C" + xi(curvature) + "," + src.y
                                     + " " + xi(1 - curvature) + "," + tgt.y
                                     + " " + tgt.x + "," + tgt.y;
                            })
                            .style("stroke", "#838383")
                            .attr("fill", "none");
```

Then for some reason the first 'link' is missing. Can anyone suggest why this might be? There's a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/v3rPs/1/). The effect that expected is missing, is that I don't have nice rounded lines like I want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that D3 matches your selection `.selectAll("path")` to your data by index by default and there is already a path in the SVG (in the `defs`). That is, the first data element matches the first path in the SVG, which is already there. Therefore, it is not in the `.enter()` selection.

The way to fix this is to specify a function in the optional second argument of `.data()` to tell D3 how to match elements, e.g.

```
.data(data.links, function(d, i) { return d + i; })
```

Comment: Brilliant - I would never have found that. As an extra do you know if there's an easy way to get arrows displaying on beziers? My vertical markers are missing...